# Create animation from png using setInterval javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my function

```
<script>
function animation(times,time,element,patch,forever,restart, frame = 0) {
    if(restart ==1){
    frame = 0;
    $(element).show();
    }
         this.interval =  setInterval(function(){
    frame++;
    $(element).attr('src',patch+''+frame+'.png');
        if(frame == times){
            if(forever == 0){
            $(element).hide();
             clearInterval(this.interval);
            } else {
            frame = 0;
            }
        }
    },time);

    }
</script>
```

It will be OK if I only use it once. But not OK if i use it much time. Help me.

Comment: In what sense does this create a GIF? Do you mean "create an animation"? Are you saying that if you use it more than once for the same element it doesn't work, or...? Please [edit] your question to describe the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour.

Comment: @nnnnnn yeah xD

Comment: 3 questions, and one answer ... clear as mud

Comment: what is the question ?